# Upload files Web Service through docker

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

Hi guys I am trying to deploy my web service to my linux server this service going to upload files to a local storage inside of this server.
Currently running in my local machine im receiving the file and save on the root folder wwwroot (should I save in a different directory?)
The Dockerfile is configured as bellow:

```bash
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 6000

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["UploadPictureLocalHost/UploadPictureLocalHost.csproj", "UploadPictureLocalHost/"]
RUN dotnet restore "UploadPictureLocalHost/UploadPictureLocalHost.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/UploadPictureLocalHost"
RUN dotnet build "UploadPictureLocalHost.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "UploadPictureLocalHost.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN mkdir /uploads
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:6000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "UploadPictureLocalHost.dll"]
```

Finally I created a docker-compose configured like this:

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  upload-localhost:
    image: name-of-repository/upload-localhost:v1
    container_name: upload-test
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 6000:6000
    volumes:
      - upload-localhost:/Upload

volumes:
  upload-localhost:
    driver: local
```

When I Upload on the server I can not find the file and my service is returning the path.

Comment: You're mounting your storage on a `/Upload` directory (with a capital `U`) inside the container, and your application needs to (be configured to) write there.  You're mounting a Docker named volume, so you won't be able to directly see its contents from the host.  Does this match your application setup?

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze On my app  I generate a folder Upload inside of wwwroot 
` if (!Directory.Exists(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\"))
  {
          Directory.CreateDirectory(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\");
   }
    using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(_environment.WebRootPath + "\\Upload\\" + objFile.FileName))
     {
                        objFile.CopyTo(fileStream);
                        fileStream.Flush();
}           
`
this approach is the right way?

Comment: @DavidMaze I access the bash and I could see the pictures inside of the folder! How can I gain access to display this or send the content to a directory?